# How to set focus to the next input box onkeyup like tab functionality

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am creating input boxes dynamically to capture inputs for a certain word (e.g. H E L L O for 'hello'). I want to set focus to the next input box after typing a single character in every input box. How should I do this?

```
<ui:repeat value="#{alphabets}" var="alphabet">
  <h:inputText value="#{alphabet.value}"/>
</ui:repeat>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That will do the trick

```
// script
function jumpNext(input) {
   $(input).next("input[type=text]").focus();
}


// jsf
<ui:repeat value="#{alphabets}" var="alphabet">
  <h:inputText value="#{alphabet.value}" onkeyup="jumpNext(this)" />
</ui:repeat>
```

[example](http://jsbin.com/ayopi4)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on how your HTML structure is. The easiest would it be to give every input an ID (which is always a good idea) and than set the id for the following inpunt in the event handler:

```
<input id="char1" onkeyup="document.getElementById('char2').focus()" />
```