# How to set focus to the input box in a table using jQuery

Tags: jquery, jsf

I am trying to set focus to the next input element in a table when onkeyup event is triggered, much similar to the functionality as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3583578/how-to-set-focus-to-the-next-input-box-onkeyup-like-tab-functionality)

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <ui:repeat value="#{alphabets}" var="alphabet">
   <td>
    <h:inputText value="#{alphabet.value}" onkeyup="jumpNext(this)" />
   </td> 
  </ui:repeat>
 </tr>
</table>
```

The script `$(input).next("input[type=text]").focus();` is not working if input elements are inside the table. And i also tried the following script 
`$(input).closest('td').next('td').find('input[type=text]').focus();` but couldn't able to get the expected behavior.

How to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use:

```
$( 'input[type=text]', $('input').parent().next('td') ).focus();
```

If you don't have other inputs don't bother filtering by type